# How do I display an image in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

So, I have a panel in Sencha Touch and I have an image which I want to display as a component in that panel. I have tried several things along the lines of:

```
   logo = {
        xtype: 'component',
        autoEl: {
            src: 'http://addressofmyimage.com/image.png',
            tag: 'img',
            style: { height: 100, width: 100 }
        }
    };
```

Then adding above component as an item in my panel. No image is displayed. All of my other components are displayed but not the image. Not even a broken-image-link icon. I can't figure this out...

I'd rather not just insert raw html, as I cannot format that as I wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably better off using a panel to display the image itself. Replace the above code with...

```
logo = {
    xtype: 'panel',
    html: '<img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" src="http://addressofmyimage.com/image.png" />'
};
```

Comment: You can use **bodyStyle** parameter as well

Comment: true, bodyStyle property with a background-image css property would work

Comment: can i add a tap handler event to it?

Answer (score 4):

You could override the Component's getElConfig method and return what you have in your autoEl object.

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    getElConfig : function() {
        return {tag: 'img',
        src: 'http://addressofmyimage.com/image.png',
        style: { height: 100, width: 100 },
        id: this.id};
    }
}
```

That method is used when the component is rendered to get the makeup of the underlying element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use src.sencha.io API to resize image as you wish. Belowed example works for me.

```
{
    xtype: 'image',
    src: 'http://src.sencha.io/100/100/http://www.skinet.com/skiing/files/imagecache/gallery_image/_images/201107/windells_hood.jpg',
    height: 100
}
```

You can find documentation [here](http://www.sencha.com/learn/how-to-use-src-sencha-io/).